# Any way to prevent elements whose positions are defined in "vw" and "vh" from sliding around during resizing?

Tags: css

I guess on the face of it you would think "but isn't them sliding around exactly what you want?" Well, yes, but the thing is, certain elements that are off-screen or otherwise out-of-view, like the next few slides of a carousel, keep sliding into view as the page resizes itself before disappearing again, and it looks kinda bad. Is this just a side effect of using vw/vh? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: hard to tell without looking at your code. "keep sliding into view as the page resizes itself before disappearing again" makes me think that you have some JS code that executes on resize, or that your layout is too complex

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element let say a div with a position top of 100vw you cannot target that specific element because you are using that specific unit. When you get the height, font-size, width or position of an element through javascript, it will return it in pixels.

You can set an elements CSS property to use vw/vh with javascript but you cannot retrieve them from the DOM because they use that unit.